# Bookdown reference {#}: underscore (_) becomes dash (-)

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

We are using bookdown to document our SQL-Queries which have a naming convention with dashes, e.g. GG1_G1SDMP01_Q001, for testing purposes we use *test_underscore*

We link to the documentation based on this technical names and using the reference, e.g. # SQL Query {#GG1_G1SDMP01_Q001}, for testing we use 
*{#test_underscore}*

Somewhere during the build the underscore is replaced by a dash, e.g.
[http://book.smart-r.net/GG1-G1SDMP01-Q001.html](http://book.smart-r.net/test-underscore.html) 
clicking the link will show

```
http://book.smart-r.net/test-underscore.html
```

The underscore has become a dash, invalidating the automatic creation for a link as a simple concatenation.

I tried to find something in the Pandoc documentation but dramatically failed and I am even not sure if pandoc is used for generating the HTML.

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.3  backports_1.1.2 bookdown_0.7    magrittr_1.5    rsconnect_0.8.5 rprojroot_1.3-2
 [7] htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.3     yaml_2.1.16     Rcpp_0.12.15    stringi_1.1.6   rmarkdown_1.8  
[13] knitr_1.18      xfun_0.1        stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.14   evaluate_0.10.1

rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.1.2’
```

Comment: It is by design: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/06bd6193d95ff26b4683c2fb2ce1ac3d66b3359e/R/html.R#L339 You cannot customize the filenames in bookdown using underscores (at least for now), unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer and great package

Answer (score 1):

AS indicated by Yihui this is by design in the coding of the bookdown package the following statement is used:

```
gsub('[^[:alnum:]]+', '-', nm)
```

A semi-elegant solution for now is to have the references at the second level

```
# Header {#TEST}

## SQL-Query {#test_underscore}
```

This will generate a link like:
http://book.smart-r.net/TEST.html#test_underscore